# Monkeypatching ActiveRecord::Base::ConnectionSpecification in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord, monkeypatching

I am trying to monkey patch `ActiveRecord::Base::ConnectionSpecification::Resolver` in Rails 3 as a workaround to an unresolved bug.

What is the cleanest way to do this and where would I put this code so it is picked up by Rails? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `config/initializers/active_record_extension.rb`

```
module ActiveRecordExtension    
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern    
  # add your instance methods here
  def foo
  end
end    
ActiveRecord::Base::ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.send(:include,ActiveRecordExtension)
```